Is this function convex or non convex? Will applying second derivative test helps?
I am trying to check whether this function is convex or not. $f(w) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{N} \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N\left ( \sigma \left ( \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{k} x _{ij}w_j\right) - G_i\right )^2$ where  $\sigma(x) =\frac{1}{1+ e^{-x}}$ and $0 \leq x_{ij},w_j, G_i\leq 1 $ and $N$ is a positive integer.

You might want to say more specifically how $\sigma$ is defined, because "sigmoid" is a somewhat generic term that refers to general shape more than anything else; I took a guess about which one you meant in my answer. Also, I noted a typo involving $n$ vs. $N$. Finally, this site can be very picky about the form of a question; the general expectation is that you show us what you've already tried, both so that answers can be tailored to you, and also to remove any impression that we're solving people's homework questions for them.

The general advice for questions of this type is to look at simple cases first. The standard (logistic) sigmoid function, defined by $f(x) = 1/(1 + e^{-x})$, is anticonvex (concave?) over $[0, \infty)$, and its square doesn't fare much better, and this provides a clue.
Take $N$ (by which I think you mean the same as $n$, the upper bound for the outer summation) to be $1$, and take $k = 2$, and take $G_1 = 0$. The expression for $f$ becomes
$$f(w_1, w_2) = \sigma(x_{11}w_1 + x_{12}w_2)^2$$
or, putting $x_1 = x_{11}$ and $x_2 = x_{12}$ to remove notational clutter,
$$f(w_1, w_2) = \sigma(x_1 w_1 + x_2 w_2)^2$$
where $(w_1, w_2) \in [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$.
We are free to choose $(x_1, x_2)$ as long $0 \leq x_1, x_2 \leq 1$, and I'll choose $x_1 = x_2 = 3/4$. Furthermore, let's look at points $(w_1, w_2) = (w, w)$ along the diagonal where $w$ is taken close to $1$, say $3/4 \leq w \leq 1$. We now have
$$f(w, w) = \sigma(3w/2)^2$$
where $9/8 \leq 3w/2 \leq 3/2$. The point behind these choices [which I'm not trying to make optimal or anything like that; I'm just going by what I can see quickly from Desmos] is that $\sigma(x)^2$ is non-convex over the interval $9/8 \leq x \leq 3/2$, and there's your answer.
But while I'm in advice-sharing mode, some general useful principles are that (1) positive linear combinations of convex functions are convex, (2) if $g: D \to [a, b]$ is convex over a convex region $D$, and $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex and monotone increasing, then $f \circ g$ is convex. (So for example, this could apply in situations like where $f: [0, a] \to \mathbb{R}$
is the squaring function.) Using principles like these can remove some of the pain of computing a second derivative outright, in cases where doing so is messy and awkward.
